# Отображения блоков JS

Tags: javascript, html

Есть разметка, хочу по клику по `а`,отображать блок, остальные скрыть.

```
<header>
    <a class="scroll" onclick="unmask(0)">
        <div class="right_top">Work</div>
    </a>
    <a class="scroll" onclick="unmask(1)">
        <div class="left_top">Mail</div>
    </a>
    <a class="scroll" onclick="unmask(2)">
        <div class="left_bottom">About</div>
    </a>
    <a class="scroll" onclick="unmask(3)">
        <div class="right_bottom">Contact</div>
    </a>
    <div class="center">Hi.</div>
</header>
<div id="blog0" class="about">
    blog0
</div>
<div id="blog1" class="work">
    blog1
</div>
<div id="blog2" class="mail">
    blog2
</div>
<div id="blog3" class="contact">
    blog3
</div>
```

Вот функция, но она не работает. В чем моя ошибка?

```
function unmask(blog) {
    for (var i; i < 4; i++) {
        if (blog === i) {
            document.getElementById(`blog${i}`).style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(`blog${i}`).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализируйте переменную счётчика в цикле, иначе будет проблема:
`var i;` определит `i` с значением `undefined`, в логическом контексте `i < 4` это вернёт `false` и цикл даже не начнётся.

```js
function unmask(blog) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (blog === i) {
      document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div[id] {
  display: none;
}
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a class="scroll" onclick="unmask(0)">
    <div class="right_top">Work</div>
  </a>
  <a class="scroll" onclick="unmask(1)">
    <div class="left_top">Mail</div>
  </a>
  <a class="scroll" onclick="unmask(2)">
    <div class="left_bottom">About</div>
  </a>
  <a class="scroll" onclick="unmask(3)">
    <div class="right_bottom">Contact</div>
  </a>
  <div class="center">Hi.</div>
</header><br />
<div id="0" class="about">
  blog0
</div>
<div id="1" class="work">
  blog1
</div>
<div id="2" class="mail">
  blog2
</div>
<div id="3" class="contact">
  blog3
</div>
```